# JMeter While controler not exiting for CSV Data Set Config

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm using 'CSV Data Set Config' with "While Controller". The CSV file has multiple values in one line (as against simple example of one variable per line - which is all over the place in net).

Example-
    Id,BobId,TarFulDate,SSRId,EDPNumber,SiteCode,CrBy,CrDate,ModBy,ModDate,Status,Version,ToolVer,ShipDate,TMDate,MaintComments,ParentId,TOName
    990:548254,18ATR0002,2018-04-02T10:00:00+05:30,548254,MEATLM-18ATR0002-001,NEATOM,LVerlli,2018-03-01T16:12:37.7230000+05:30,PFibacher,2018-05-15T12:19:33+05:30,Submitted,12,0,1,2018-04-02T10:00:00+05:30,,547011,18ATR0002-0600-0-2

I'm using a "While Controller". The "While Condition" is not working. It keeps on running in infinite loop. However, the values it picked from CSV file are correct. It reads all the values from the file and keeps on repeating.

I tried the following option, but none of them worked -

```
${__javaScript("${Id}" != "<EOF>",)}
${__javaScript(${Id} != null,)}
${__groovy(!vars.get('Id').equals('<EOF>'),)}
${__jexl3("${Id}" != "<EOF>")} 
${__jexl3(${Id} != null)} 
${__jexl3(${Id} != "<EOF>")} 
${__jexl3('${Id}' != '<EOF>')}
```

I expect the while controller to exit and Application to stop when all the rows from csv file is processed.

Answer (score 1):

You should set [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) parameters `Recycle on EOF?` as false, and `Stop thread on EOF?` as false, to get EOF value

> When the end of file (EOF) is reached, and the recycle option is true, reading starts again with the first line of the file.
>
> If the recycle option is false, and stopThread is false, then all the variables are set to  when the end of file is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to make it works following this:

1- in the while condition put this condition:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('myVar') == null || (vars.get('myVar') as String) !="<EOF>",)}
```

2- add a if controller inside the while and put the sampler inside it, then in the if condition put this:

```
${__javaScript(vars.get("myVar")!="<EOF>")}
```